# Are questions about how to build computers allowed?

Tags: discussion

I ran into a question asking about, basically, where to put a piece of hardware and not about what hardware to get. Is this acceptable? I don't think this kind of question can be diverted to Superuser since it isn't asking about how a technology works or anything like that.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28/are-diy-hardware-recommendations-allowed?rq=1)

Comment: @HDE That question isn't related. What I'm talking about is someone asking _how to use_ a piece of hardware. This doesn't involve DIY computers.

Comment: Sorry; you talked about building a computer in the title, which seemed pretty DIY.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm allowed to directly link the question I'm talking about. If I can, let me know. The person asked about where to place a PCIe x4 SSD in his computer.

Comment: [This one](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82/for-intel-pcie-400gb-drive-does-it-matter-what-type-pcie-slot-i-need)? I think I get what you mean, then.

Comment: That's the one. Seems a bit between topics doesn't it?

Comment: It does indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very strongly against allowing these. We don't want to become spec-and-build-my-computer.SE, we want to be hardwarerecs.SE. If we allow assembly questions, we dilute the scope. We really shouldn't do that, *especially* a day into private beta.

Comment: Counterpoint: what would be so bad about this site being computer-hardware.SE?

Comment: @Gilles It's hard enough to build up an expert base for hardware recommendations alone - we've seen that with SR. I'm worried that if we dilute the scope it's going to be even harder. Why do that when (I think?) the "where does the thingy go in my new computer" would be on-topic for Super User.

Comment: On the contrary, it's easier to build up an expert base on hardware than on the specific subtopic of hardware recommendations. Hardware recommendations is something most people only care about sporadically, when they're about to buy some new item. Hardware questions come up a lot more often when people tweak or configure the stuff they already have.

Answer (score 2):

I think such a question would be OK only if the question is narrowly focused.

Which specific devices (with links to specs.), and a specific question regarding connection, function or compatibility.

Anything more general than that should be off-topic as "Too Broad".